# open3: exec of failed at perl 5.18.2

Tags: perl, exec, archive, 7zip, sevenzipsharp

I wrote perl script for zipping the files with [Archive::SevenZip](http://p3rl.org/Archive::SevenZip) module.

I got this error

> open3: exec of 7z -y -bd l -slt "Filelocation" failed at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Archive/SevenZip.pm.

I can't able to resolve that.

Comment: How we could help without seeing of _your_ code? See: [mcve] (But, guessing - try replace the `Filelocation` with some actual path).

Comment: Do you have `7z` installed? Is it on your path?

Answer (score 2):

Archive::SevenZip is using `open3` to execute the command-line utility `7z`. That message indicates the call to `exec` is failing.

Most likely problem: `7z` isn't installed on your machine.

If you think that's not the problem,

1. Edit the file named by `perldoc -lm IPC::Open3`.
2. Replace

   ```
   exec @cmd or do {
       carp "$Me: exec of @cmd failed";
   ```

   with

   ```
   exec @_ or do {
       local($")=(" ");
       croak "$Me: exec of @_ failed: $!";
   };
   ```

   (This change is already present in newer versions of IPC::Open3.)
3. Rerun the program.
4. Provide the more detailed error message.

Comment: I checked the changes are already in my system. i installed 7z in my machine."Unexpected line in 7zip output, hope that's OK: [] at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Archive/SevenZip.pm line 256, <GEN6> line 7." still got this error. And the line in the file is                                         
"if( $output[0] =~ /^----------\s*$/ ) {
 shift @output;
 } else {
warn "Unexpected line in 7zip output, hope that's OK: [$output[0]]";
};"

Comment: Re "*I checked the changes are already in my system*", The error message you posted in the OP shows otherwise. You have have used the `perldoc` that was installed by a different `perl` then the `perl` used when you obtained the error message.

Comment: The warning you are now asking about indicates that `7z` provided different output than expected.